# transfer data of 5 activity pages 26 edit text fields and calculate in last android activity

Tags: android, eclipse

my problem is related to android application so far i was able to create 5 different activities with variables and onclick button to pass on next activity...

```
    public class Abc extends Activity{
Button one2five;
EditText edtA, edtB, edtC, edtD, edtE, edtF;
String tA, tB, tC, tD, tE, tF;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abc);
        one2five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btp1);
        edtA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etA);
        tA = edtA.getText().toString();
        edtB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etB);
        tB = edtB.getText().toString();
        edtC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etC);
        tC = edtC.getText().toString();
        edtD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etD);
        tD = edtD.getText().toString();
        edtE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etE);
        tE = edtE.getText().toString();
        edtF = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etF);
        tF = edtF.getText().toString();
        one2five.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent openg2j = new Intent("com.sport.sport.G2J");
                startActivity(openg2j);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Now with this as a base i created 4 more pages and total 26 different edittext fields.

**My objective is:-**
get all edit text in one calculate page.
perform claculation and post result in on One page.

**Problem:-**
get user text **all decimal numbers**
user get prompt if a field is left blank with highlighted field.
if a user press back previous activity should have previously entered values.

can any one help me to solve this issue..
thanks 
monika

Comment: create a singleton class(a statc class shared among all activities) which stores all information of all activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With various methodology you can handle it

1- either define all the Field at application Level this will keep alive all the field alive untill and unless application is alive 
Pros: Once defined use through out the application 
cons: once app close data lost.

2- pass value in intent handle it in next activity and then combine field of previous and current activity and pass it on to next activity
Pros: use Fields in back and forth activity 
cons: once app close data lost.
3- Save field in shared preferences and use it any time either app is alive or not 
pros: data is saved once committed.

4- you can use ArrayList and add data in every current to next activity context switching 
so its up to you with which scenario you want to use it

and if you want to have data in previous activity 
you can override method onbackpressed and perform your functionality as accordingly

Sample code Using Method 2

Modified   code in the question

```
     public class Abc extends Activity{
Button one2five;
EditText edtA, edtB, edtC, edtD, edtE, edtF;
String tA, tB, tC, tD, tE, tF;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abc);
        one2five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btp1);
        edtA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etA);
        tA = edtA.getText().toString();
        edtB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etB);
        tB = edtB.getText().toString();
        edtC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etC);
        tC = edtC.getText().toString();
        edtD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etD);
        tD = edtD.getText().toString();
        edtE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etE);
        tE = edtE.getText().toString();
        edtF = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etF);
        tF = edtF.getText().toString();
        one2five.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent openg2j = new Intent("com.sport.sport.G2J");
                openg2j .putExtra("field1Data", tA);
                openg2j .putExtra("field2Data", tB);
                openg2j .putExtra("field3Data", tC);
                openg2j .putExtra("field4Data", tD);
                openg2j .putExtra("field5Data", tE);

                startActivity(openg2j);
            }
        });

    }
```

this is how you can send data from current class to next Class
}

**Edited :**

in 2ndActivity you can get that data like ,

```
String field5Data = getIntent().getStringExtra("field5Data") ;
```

Comment: Hi Usman, thanks for understanding my query, i would like to use scenario 1 and 2 method, could you please code for me in above activity i pasted,  --- I have learned basics from youtube newboston tutorials i m kinda new for it

Comment: Thanks Usman, amazing one more small question does this data will be available till my last activity means the calculation page?? FYI this calculation page is after 5 different activity..     --- or alternatively i can transfer this data to calculation page directly and button will take me to next activity.. is it possible??  --- i am thinking two intents one transferring data to claculation page and one intent to go to next form...

Comment: passing value from current to next is a sequential means like this way activity1->activity2->activity3 and so on. and if you are on activity2 and onbackpressed you want your data of activity1 in their respective field then you need to send data in the similar way as you are sending it from activty1 to activity2. but on sending back data (from activity2 to activity1) you need to override method onbackpressed hope this will help yoo in your understanding of sending data

Comment: For your 2ndComment ( or question ) you can use , SharedPreference or , you can use Static variable ( but not recommended )

Comment: Look when ever you get some_value store it in SharedPreference , and when ever you want it just fetch it .

Comment: Refer , @Kalai.G answer , it will help you .

Comment: thanks tushar but still i dont get it how to use it, Usman code i understood perfectly...  secondly if i convert data into string in next activity do i have to again putextra for 3rd activity?... in that scenario i like sharedpreferences .. please guide

Comment: No need to pass monika

Comment: try this project from : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4dm3xx5uppqodc4/dFHqcSE5gw/SharedPreferenceExample

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the datas throughout the application then use "SHARED PEFERENCES"

Saving the values:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();    
    editor.putInt(String.valueOf(key), value);//store int values, can use string,arrays,etc 
    editor.commit();
```

Load the saved values:

```
        SharedPreferences getProgramPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    int Index = getProgramPrefs.getInt(String.valueOf(key), -1);
```

and for this "a user press back previous activity should have previously entered values", you can try with finish() or by loading the preference values

```
                         finish();
```

Comment: Thanks Kalai, I have never seen this code could you please essemble my code so that i can get full picture..

Comment: i want to save data for once, but on restart can i have option for reset data??

Comment: @Monika Actually datas get stored in the form of xml with key and its values.save the values in onclick SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF",0);SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();editor.putExtra("field1Data", tA);editor.putExtra("field2Data", tB);
and in any activity u can fetch those with,  SharedPreferences getProgramPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);String txt1=getProgramPrefs.getString("field1Data");String txt2= getProgramPrefs.getString("field2Data"); hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create `ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();` for each activity when `onClick()`.  Press "add all data" to `ArrayList`, pass this `ArrayList` into intent, put extra, on 2,3,4 activity you get previous activity data from `getIntent()` add your current activity data and pass on next activity and last activity do your calculation with previous and current data.

```
/**First Activity**/

    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        data.clear();
        data.add(tA);
        --------------
        --------------
        data.add(tZ);


        Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.class, FirstActivity.this);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("IN_PREVIOUS_DATA", data);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    /**Second Activity**/

    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        data.clear();
        data.addAll((ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("IN_PREVIOUS_DATA"));
        data.add(tA);
        --------------
        --------------
        data.add(tZ);


        Intent intent = new Intent(ThirdActivity.class, SecondActivity.this);
        intent.putExtra("IN_PREVIOUS_DATA", data);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: i have not learned array till now, could you please help on code